# Easily editing base class variables from inherited class

Tags: python, class, object, inheritance, attributes

#### How does communication between base classes and inherited classes work?

I have a data class in my python code ( storing all important values, duh ), I tried inheriting new subclasses from the *data base class*, everything worked fine except the fact that the classes were not actually communicating ( when one class variable was changed in a subclass, the class attribute **was not** changed in the base class nor any other subclasses.

I guess I just failed to understand how inheritance works, **my question is**: Does inheritance keep any connection to the base classes, or are the values set at the time of inheritance?

If there is any connection, how do you easily manipulate base class variables from a subclass ( I tried it with the *cls* variable to access base class variables, didn't work out )

#### Example

```
class Base:
    x = 'baseclass var' # The value I want to edit

class Subclass(Base):
    @classmethod(cls)
        ???edit_base_x_var_here??? # This is the part I don't know
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do that in this way:

```
class Base:
    x = 'baseclass var' # The value I want to edit

class Subclass(Base):
    @classmethod
    def change_base_x(cls):
        Base.x = 'nothing'


print Subclass.x
Subclass.change_base_x()
print Subclass.x
```

furthermore, you don't have to use `@classmethod`, it could be staticmethod, because you don't need current class object `cls`:

```
class Base:
    x = 'baseclass var' # The value I want to edit

class Subclass(Base):
    @staticmethod
    def change_base_x():
        Base.x = 'nothing'
```

EDITED:

According to your question, about other way. Yes it is, but not so pretty. I would say more. If you want to change variable of base class, then you will do it globally though, so that option with assigning to `Base.x` is the best way you can achieve that.

Comment: I already know this method, my question was if there is any better way to achieve this.

Comment: Okay so this is the most convenient way to achieve my goal?